# Minix 3.2.1 Makefile issue

Tags: minix, makefile

I'm trying to run make with the below Makefile and I get the following error `Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.`. This Makefile is the original file from Minix 3.2.1. I haven't done any changes. I check from the tabs problem. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

```
# Makefile for the kernel image.
.include <bsd.own.mk>
.include "nbsd.config"

.include <bsd.own.mk>
.include <bsd.sys.mk>

u=/usr
MDEC=   /usr/mdec
GEN_FILES=  *.bak image kernel *.iso *.iso.gz cdfdimage rootimage src

# LSC detect where were built the objects files
PROGROOT:= ..
.if "${MAKEOBJDIR:S,${.CURDIR},,}" != ""
PROGROOT:= ${MAKEOBJDIR:S,releasetools,,}
.endif

# Specify the programs that are part of the system image.
KERNEL= ${PROGROOT}/kernel/kernel
# PROGRAMS are in the order they should be loaded by boot
PROGRAMS+= ${PROGROOT}/servers/ds/ds
PROGRAMS+= ${PROGROOT}/servers/rs/rs
PROGRAMS+= ${PROGROOT}/servers/pm/pm
PROGRAMS+= ${PROGROOT}/servers/sched/sched
PROGRAMS+= ${PROGROOT}/servers/vfs/vfs
PROGRAMS+= ${PROGROOT}/drivers/memory/memory
.if ${MACHINE_ARCH} == "i386"
PROGRAMS+= ${PROGROOT}/drivers/log/log
.endif
PROGRAMS+= ${PROGROOT}/drivers/tty/tty
PROGRAMS+= ${PROGROOT}/servers/mfs/mfs
PROGRAMS+= ${PROGROOT}/servers/vm/vm
PROGRAMS+= ${PROGROOT}/servers/pfs/pfs
PROGRAMS+= ${PROGROOT}/servers/init/init

usage:  
    @echo " " >&2
    @echo "Master Makefile to create new MINIX configuration." >& 2
    @echo "Root privileges are required." >&2
    @echo " " >&2
    @echo "Usage:" >&2
    @echo " make includes   # Install include files" >&2
    @echo " make depend     # Generate dependency files" >&2
    @echo " make services   # Compile and install all services" >&2
    @echo " make install    # Make image, and install to hard disk" >&2
    @echo " make hdboot     # Make image, and install to hard disk" >&2
    @echo " make bootable   # Make hard disk bootable" >&2
    @echo " make nbsd_fetch # Download current NetBSD reference sources" >&2
    @echo " make nbsd_diff  # Update minix-port.patch in NetBSD sources" >&2
    @echo " make clean      # Remove all compiler results, except libs" >&2
    @echo " " >&2
    @echo "To create a fresh MINIX configuration, try:" >&2
    @echo " make clean install      # new boot image" >&2
    @echo " make fresh install      # new everything" >&2
    @echo " " >&2

all: services

# rebuild the program or system libraries
includes:
    $(MAKE) -C ../ includes

depend: includes .gitignore
    $(MAKE) -C ../ depend

.gitignore: Makefile
    echo $(GEN_FILES) | tr ' ' '\n' >.gitignore

services: includes kernel servers .WAIT drivers

kernel: includes
    $(MAKE) -C ../kernel 

servers: includes
    $(MAKE) -C ../servers all install

drivers: includes servers
    $(MAKE) -C ../drivers all install

# make bootable and place system images
bootable:
    exec su root mkboot bootable ${DESTDIR}

hdboot: services .WAIT do-hdboot

do-hdboot: 
    @rm -rf ${DESTDIR}/boot/minix/.temp/
    ${INSTALL_DIR} ${DESTDIR}/boot/minix/.temp
# mod_0 is used to make alphabetical order equal to the boot order
    @n=0;                           \
    for i in ${PROGRAMS};                   \
    do                          \
    n=`expr $$n + 1`;                   \
    [ "$$n" -ge 10 ] && prefix="mod" || prefix="mod0";  \
    newname="${DESTDIR}/boot/minix/.temp/$${prefix}$${n}_`basename $$i`"; \
    ${INSTALL} $$i $$newname;               \
    done
    @cp ${PROGROOT}/kernel/kernel ${DESTDIR}/boot/minix/.temp/
    @if [ "${MKINSTALLBOOT:Uno}" != "no" ] ; then       \
    ${STRIP} -s ${DESTDIR}/boot/minix/.temp/* ;     \
    gzip ${DESTDIR}/boot/minix/.temp/mod* ;         \
    ${HOST_SH} mkboot hdboot ${DESTDIR};            \
    ${HOST_SH} ../commands/update_bootcfg/update_bootcfg.sh;\
    else                            \
    ${INSTALL_DIR} ${DESTDIR}/multiboot;            \
    ${INSTALL} ${DESTDIR}/boot/minix/.temp/* ${DESTDIR}/multiboot;  \
    fi

install:
    ${MAKE} includes services hdboot

# download and update NetBSD reference sources.
nbsd_fetch:
    export CVS_RSH=ssh;                             \
    export OLDPWD=`pwd`;                            \
    echo "retrieving hierarchies from ${NBSD_CVSROOT}";         \
    IFS=,;                                  \
    cd ..;                                  \
    cat releasetools/nbsd_ports | grep -v '^#' | while read port ;      \
    do  set $$port;                         \
        date=$$1; minixpath=$$2; origpath=$$3;              \
        if [ $$# -lt 3 ]; then origpath=$$2; fi;            \
        echo "retrieving $$origpath ..";                \
        cvs -q -d ${NBSD_CVSROOT} co -N -D "$$date UTC" -d nbsdsrc "src/$$origpath" ; \
    done;                                   \
    cd $${OLDPWD};

nbsd_diff:
    find .. -name minix-port.patch | xargs rm
    cat nbsd_ports | grep -v '^#' | \
    ( cd .. && awk -F, '{ minixpath=$$2; origpath=$$3; if(NF < 3) { origpath=$$2; } system("sh releasetools/nbsd_diff.sh " \
       "nbsdsrc/src/"origpath" "minixpath" "minixpath"/minix-port.patch");}' )
    find .. -name minix-port.patch | xargs wc -l | sort -n


# clean up compile results
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C ../kernel $@
    $(MAKE) -C ../servers $@
    $(MAKE) -C ../drivers $@
    rm -rf $(GEN_FILES)

cleandepend::
    $(MAKE) -C ../kernel $@
    $(MAKE) -C ../servers  $@
    $(MAKE) -C ../drivers  $@
```

Comment: We need to know what version of `make` you are using. Does running `make --version` tell you this? If so edit your question to inlclude the output of that command.

Comment: it doesn't look like a `makefile` for `GNU make`, maybe in Minix they use some other kind of `make`?

Comment: When I run make --version I get : GNU Make 4.1

Answer (score 0):

MINIX uses BSD `make`, which typically uses `.` to prefix its specific extensions. You installed GNU `make`, which has another set of extensions, *not* prefixed with `.`; furthermore you put GNU `make` ahead in the `PATH` order without renaming it. This is not going to take off.

What we usually do is to name GNU `make` under the name `gmake` or `gnumake`, and invoke it under that name when needed (for example, to compile packages from GNU ecosystem, or with a strong Linux bias.)

Another possibility you might consider is to install (if not already done) the `bmake` package, and uses that command when trying to compile programs which expect the BSD breed of `make` (this includes MINIX itself.)